# How to display approve button for a particular user

Tags: xpages

![hierarchical structure][1]Previously we were using @functions to create forms and those forms are hierarchical structure means.

Initiator raises the form and sends to particular dept officer

Department officer approves and sends to next authority(Dept HOD) for approval

Finally, Dept HOD approves the form.

Now I want these structure in xpages. Please help me with how to create.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what exactly you're asking. Please try explaining the problem in more detail and actually showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please rephrase your post. As far as I understand you want context aware buttons.

Comment: Might be a case of 'English isn't a first choice language' - be nice, let him live!

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern of application creation hasn't changed. You show and hide information based on values in the documents. In classic Notes application you use "HideWhen" formulas using the @Formula language. These formulas work on the current paragraph.

In XPages you use the "visible" property. Clicking on the diamond shape next to visible allows you to enter code there. That code is written in server-side JavaScript.

The difference: in classic Notes a result of `true` means the whole row gets hidden, in XPages: the element (and all its children) is visible.

You might want to learn more about XPages following [my guide](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/Learning-XPages) and do the [27 Exercises](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/tutorial-intro-to-xpages.htm)

Comment: Another good place to learn XPages might be NotesIn9.com.  Many videos available there going back to 2009.